# Prove properties of exponential function using a limit definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am using ${\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^{n}}=e^x$ and want to show that $e^{x+y} =e^xe^y$ and $e^{-x}=(e^x)^{-1}$ using only the given limit.

The trouble is that I believe $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ is not true for large values of $n$

Comment: That limit equation is always true.  In particular it's true when you replace the $x$'s with $z$'s: where you define $z=x+y$.  Or when you define $z=-1$.

Comment: The equation $e^{x+y} = e^{x}e^{y}$ does not depend on an integer $n$. Don't confuse the limit with the terms in  the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1:  Assume $x+y>0$

Write $e^{x+y}={\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{(x+y)}{n} \right)^{n}}$ and substitute $\frac1m=\frac{x+y}{n}$.

$$e^{x+y}={\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{(x+y)}{n} \right)^{n}}={\displaystyle \lim_{m \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^{m(x+y)}}=\left({\displaystyle \lim_{m \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{m} \right)^{m}}\right)^{x+y}=e^xe^y$$

which completes the proof for Case 1, $x+y>0$.

Case 2: $x+y=0$.  This case for is trivial.

Case 3:  $x+y<0$

When $x+y<0$, we begin by making the substitution $\frac{1}{m} = -\frac{x+y}{n}$.  We proceed analogously thereafter by making use of the identity

$$e^{-1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Comment: Nice answer, just a follow up which properties of the limit do we need to pay attention to?

Comment: Thank you! There were no specific properties that we needed.  It's just a simple substitution.  Of course, we tacitly assumed $x+y>0$.  But the other case can be handled similarly.

Comment: Can you show $e^{-x}=(e^x)^{-1}$

Comment: Note that $m$ will not be an integer after the substitution. You have to prove first that $\lim_{z\to\infty}(1+x/z)^z=e^x$ (where $z$ is supposed to be a “continuous” variable).

Comment: @egreg Where in the stated definition was $n$ restricted to be an integer?

Comment: @Dr.MV: I have to agree here with egreg. When the limit is of the form $n \to \infty$ then it is implicitly assumed that $n$ is an integer **unless otherwise stated.** Proper answer has been provided by Jack D'Aurizio.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The OP believed otherwise apparently.  The only requirement in the proof is that $\lim_{m \to \infty} (1+m^{-1})^m=e$.  Are you suggesting that this is not true if $m$ is not an integer?  If so, that belief is unfounded.

Comment: @Dr.MV: the result is true even if $m$ is not an integer, but using that as a definition of $e$ is very complicated because it involves exponents which may be irrational.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  See my answer here.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198994/proof-relating-to-limit-definition-of-e/1199022#1199022    Does that seem complicated to you?  And no integer restrictions!

Comment: @Dr.MV: I don't want to continue this further. The question you refer to assumes that $\log x$ is defined as integral and $e^{x}$ is the inverse. This is technically the easiest approach. In the current question the starting point is the definition $e^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + x/n)^{n}$ and this is simpler to handle if $n$ is assumed an integer. See my posts on this topic at http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-1.html

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I like your blog! Very nice.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You say that using that as a definition of $e$ is complicated because of irrational exponents. I don't think so, because one can get from rational exponents to irrational exponents easily by using continuity.

Comment: @PoderRac: well that is rather easily said than done. Any definition of irrational exponents based on continuity and the definition of rational exponents is far complicated. By habit Rudin chooses this complicated route and defines $b^x=\sup\{b^t\mid t\in\mathbb {Q}, t\leq x\} $ for $b>1$. I have replaces the sup with limits and given an exposition in [this blog post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html?m=0).

Comment: @poderrac I suggest you read Paramanand's blog page articles.  They're instructive and should facilitate the discussion you're having.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh After reading your blog, I still think it's pretty intuitive, but that's probably a matter of opinion.

Comment: @poderrac Mathematics is a rigorous and logical discipline, not one that relies on your intuition, which might very well be flawed.

Comment: @MarkViola I think you misunderstood me, by "it" I meant *the proof using continuity* is pretty intuitive.

Comment: @poderrac Again, intuition is not sufficient.

Comment: @MarkViola I did not say that intuition is sufficient, but the proof using continuity feels very motivated and I like it.

Answer (score 6):

Since
$$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\cdot\left(1+\frac{y}{n}\right)^n = \left(1+\frac{x+y}{n}+\frac{xy}{n^2}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{x+y}{n}\right)^n\cdot\left(1+\frac{xy}{n^2+nx+ny}\right)^n$$
we just need to show that for any $x,y$ we have:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{xy}{n^2+nx+ny}\right)^n=1\tag{1}$$
that follows from:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{xy}{n^2}\right)^n=1.\tag{2}$$

Comment: How do you prove the last limit?

Comment: @croraf: consider that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{xy}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}=e^{xy},$$ giving that the argument of the limit behaves like $e^{xy/n} \approx 1+\frac{xy}{n}$ for large values of $n$.